# Can Database Mirroring Be Setup On MS SQLServer Between Two Clusters

Tags: sql-server, database, cluster-computing, mirroring

Using Microsoft SQL Server's database mirroring capability, can the mirroring occur between two clusters? All of the examples in MSDN show a topology indicating single servers for both the principal and mirror server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in 2005 and 2008, the answer is [yes](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/dbmirfaq.mspx#EXB). I don't personally have experience with clustering, so I don't have tips on how to set it up or what to watch after you do.